# It is possible to change the display settings of an Android device?

Tags: android, sdk, settings

I would like to hear about possible ways to change the font size of all text on an Android device via Native React or Flutter

I no longer have immediate knowledge on the subject and I would love to get help

Comment: Is it a question  about `Flutter` or `Native React`? you need to ask specific question, check more on [/minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It's wrong if it's for both?